# How is the run time stack maintained after a buffer is injected with malicious code?

Tags: callstack, buffer-overflow

I was reading the following paper on buffer overflow :  http://www1.telhai.ac.il/sources/private/academic/cs/557/2659/Materials/Smashing.pdf

According to the examples in the paper, the attacker injects code in the buffer which is overflowed and modifies the return address to point to the address of the buffer. Since, the injected code and the local variables both lie on the stack , shouldn't the attacker make sure that she/he has left enough space for local variables before overflowing the buffer with the code? In broad sense, I m confused how stack would be maintained when both the code and local variables are there on the stack ....are there chances of local variables overwriting the injected code ???

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to not use any local variables. This isn't necessarily a big constraint on code that is going to be small and do its work by calling into something else anyway. (Very relative on saying its not a big constraint, it's beyond me tbh but since this isn't the easiest code to write, its not a big constraint in that context).

That's not even necessary though. A stack will look something like:

```
Function A Arg 2
Function A Arg 1
Function A Arg 0
Return Address into caller
Function A Local 1
Function A Local 0
Function B Arg 1
Function B Arg 0
Return Address into place in Function A's executable code.
Function B Local 2
Function B Local 1
Function B Local 0
Function C Arg 0
Return Address into place in Function B's executable code.
Function C Local 3
Function C Local 2
Function C Local 1
Function C Local 0
...
```

A buffer overflow tricks it into looking like:

```
Function A Arg 2
Function A Arg 1
Function A Arg 0
Return Address into caller
Function A Local 1
NastyCode bytes 0-3
NastyCode bytes 4-7
NastyCode bytes 8-B
NastyCode bytes C-E
NastyCode bytes F-10
NastyCode bytes 10-13
NastyCode bytes 14-17
NastyCode bytes 18-1B
NastyCode bytes 1F-20
...
NastyCode arg 0 (etc.)
Return Address (of NastyCode [may not even be valid, may return to original caller, or may jump into something it'll set up]).
NastyCode Local 2
NastyCode Local 1
NastyCode Local 0
Return Address (should be of Function F, into a point in Function E but it's changed to point to byte 0 of NastyCode)
Function F Local 2
Function F Local 1
Function F Local 0
```

So the executable code written into the stack can be away from the local varaibles of that code.

Comment: Its still not clear to me that in case is the injected code uses local variable then how things will work .
According to Intelx86, frame pointer/base pointer for the stack is stored below the return address , therefore when trying to modify the return address we are modifying the frame pointer(fp) as well . Now if my injected code uses local variables and my modified fp points to a random location which is not accessible then the code might fail.....

Comment: In the above, the frame pointer was pointing at the return address just above "Function F Local 2". Above that had "Function F Arg 0" (or perhaps locals from Function E, or its return address if F had no args, and E no locals, etc). We either fill the area of the stack above the FP our code and locals, or fill the area below it (more realistic, should have made that my example), and we change the address FP points at to this code (don't change FP itself). Then the return jumps into the code. Again though, we don't really need locals - a small one-off function can just use hard-coded values.

Comment: i was following the paper I mentioned and according to which between the return address and locals of function f (from this example), the computer stores base pointer (ebp in intel architecture) , which also gets modified when writing the code...